# Soap connection with mantisbt

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, mantis

I'm trying to make a soap connection with the web service mantis bug tracker for an personnal appli.

```
  public function issues_get($username, $password) {
    try {
       $client = new SoapClient($this->adresse);
        $response = $client->mc_filter_get_issues($username, $password, $this->projectId, $this->ersFilter, 0, 0);
        $response = convert::object2array($response);
        return $response;
    }
    catch (SoapFault $e){
        echo $e->faultcode; 
        //$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

What is wrong ?

$this->adresse = "http://localhost/mantisbt/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl"

when i go at this adress with the browser i see the correct XHTML file

it's this line where ther is an error : `$client = new SoapClient($this->adresse);`

Thanks for help.

Comment: You say you're seeing XHTML when you go to the WSDL link? That doesn't sound right -- a wsdl link should not give XHTML; it should give WSDL-format XML.

Comment: when i go on this adress : "http://localhost/mantisbt/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl"  i have this page http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=732454Sanstitre.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem. I dont know why but the error was "localhost". I put the IP adress and the script work fine.

```
$this->adresse = "http://192.x.x.x.x/mantisbt/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl"
```

thanks all for help :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct entry point is `http://localhost/mantisbt/api/soap/mantisconnect.php` ( leave out the `?wsdl` part ).